# Unsigned VHDL conversion not working

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity fourToSixteenDecoder is
    port ( a : in std_logic_vector(0 to 3); 
              EN : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Y : out std_logic_vector(0 to 15));
end fourToSixteenDecoder;

architecture Behavioral of fourToSixteenDecoder is
begin
    process(a, EN)
    variable inputs : integer := conv_integer(unsigned(a));
    variable Y_c : std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    begin
        Y_c := X"0000";
        if (EN = '1') then
            Y_c(inputs) := '1';
        elsif (EN = '0') then
            Y_c := X"0000";
        end if;
        Y <= Y_c;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Trying to make a 4-16 Decoder, however, I am trying to use conversion between integer and SLV to do bit indexing assignment, but the conversion does not work.

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "..." Line 40: Syntax error near "b".
```

Also tried

```
to_integer(unsigned())
integer(unsigned())
integer(to_unsigned())
to_integer(to_unsigned())
use IEEE.ARITH and IEEE.STD_LOGIC.UNSIGNED
```

No solution.

Comment: This is 34 lines long. So which is line 40? The posted code compiles if you change `conv_integer` to `to_integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion routine is call `to_integer` in package numeric_std, and for an unsigned produces a natural range integer.

With `variable inputs : integer := to_integer(unsigned(a));` inputs would be initialized to the initial value of `a` converted to an integer (likely `0` if `a` is  uninitialized (all `'U'`s).

There is no other assignment to `inputs` and `inputs` wouldn't change with `a` value changes.

Replace the variable `inputs` declaration with

```
    variable inputs: integer range 0 to 15;
```

which restricts the range of inputs to the index range of  `Y_c`.

Add

```
    inputs := to_integer(unsigned(a));
```

as a first sequential statement to the process.

The two assignments:

```
        Y_c := X"0000";
```

are redundant. The elsif can be eliminated:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fourToSixteenDecoder is
    port ( 
        a:  in  std_logic_vector(0 to 3); 
        EN: in  std_logic;
        Y:  out std_logic_vector(0 to 15)
    );
end entity fourToSixteenDecoder;

architecture Behavioral of fourToSixteenDecoder is
begin
    process(a, EN)
        -- variable inputs : integer := conv_integer(unsigned(a));
        variable inputs: integer range 0 to 15;
        variable Y_c:    std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    begin
        inputs := to_integer(unsigned(a));  -- ADDED
        Y_c := X"0000";
        if  EN = '1' then
            Y_c(inputs) := '1';
        -- elsif (EN = '0') then
        --     Y_c := X"0000";
        end if;
        Y <= Y_c;
    end process;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and simulates. Notice the parentheses around the if statement conditions aren't needed.

A testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_4to16 is
end entity;

architecture fum of tb_4to16 is
    signal a:   std_logic_vector (0 to 3) := (others => '0');
    signal EN:  std_logic;
    signal Y:   std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
begin
DUT:
        entity work.fourtosixteendecoder
        port map (
            a => a,
            EN => EN,
            Y => Y
        );
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            EN <= '0';
            a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,4));
            wait for 10 ns;
            EN <='1';
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        EN <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The results:
[image: tb_4to6.png]